# How to alter decimal scale and precision in psycopg2 using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using the script that contains the code below

```
    query = """ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name NUMERIC (22,6);"""
    
    self.cursor.execute(query)
    self.connection.commit()
```

but i get error below

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "NUMERIC"
```

Have you encountered error like this? I have searched nothing is out on the internet.

PS: I have used **DECIMAL** instead of **Numeric**, same error appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [the PostgreSQL documentation for `ALTER TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html), you'll see you need to use the `TYPE` keyword (mandatory):

```
ALTER [ COLUMN ] column_name [ SET DATA ] TYPE data_type [ COLLATE collation ]
      [ USING expression ]
```

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name TYPE NUMERIC (22,6)
```

Also, this error shows that this is a syntax error coming from PostgreSQL. Practically, your question has nothing to do with Python or Psycopg2:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "NUMERIC"
```

Comment: Numeric is my data type

Comment: `TYPE` is the keyword to change the data type, `data_type` is what you replace with your data type. The `TYPE` keyword is missing in your example.

Comment: got you ,worked thanks.